# Braided Monoidal 2-categories with duals

Tags: ct.category-theory, knot-theory, 2-knots, at.algebraic-topology, quantum-groups

Which categorifications give explicit braided monoidal 2-categories with duals? 
This question is in response to Ben Webster's questions in recent history. The point is that given a braided monoidal 2-category with duals (other than the 2-category of tangle surfaces) an invariant of knotted surfaces can be constructed.

I've been told that Lurie's work gives examples, but I don't know where to look therein.

Answer (score 8):

Khovanov homology can be thought of as a braided monoidal 2-category with duals, i.e. a 4-category with duals where the 0- and 1-morphisms are trivial.

0-morphisms: an unmarked point

1-morphisms: an unmarked interval

2-morphisms: a disk with some points in it

3-morphisms: a tangle in a 3-ball

4-morphisms: Given tangles $T_1$ and $T_2$ with matching boundary conditions, we have a closed link $\overline{T_1}\cup T_2$ in the 4-sphere.  Define $Mor(T_1 \to T_2)$ to be $Kh(\overline{T_1}\cup T_2)$, the Khovanov homology of this link.

Composition and duality in dimensions 0 through 3 are obvious, since we have geometrically defined morphisms in those dimensions.  Once we have the well-known fact that surface bordisms act on Khovanov homology, it's relatively little additional work to define composition and duality for 4-morphisms.

For a few more details, see these [slides from a talk](http://canyon23.net/math/talks/Kh%20200704.pdf).

Unfortunately from your point of view, Rasmussen showed that the invariants of knotted tori in $B^4$ that arise from this 4-category are always trivial (or rather always equal to 2, the same as an unknotted torus).  On the other hand, I think the TQFT corresponding to this 4-category will provide interesting invariants of 4-manifolds (work in progress).

Comment: Kevin, Thanks. I did not recognize you at first at UCR, and did not really get a chance to say hello. Both Ramussen and Tanako showed the 2-knot invariant from KhoHo was trivial; Tanaka did so after Shin Satoh, Masahico Saito and I did so for a large number of cases. 

Perhaps the question is in regard to other such constructions. Oszvath-Szabo, or the sl(3) invariant, for example.  

Comment: @Scott, the fact that the invariants of 2-knots are trivial isn't that interesting. In particular, Khovanov homology gives interesting invariants 2-tangles.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A$ be an $E_3$-algebra, so that $A$ is an $E_2$-algebra in the category of $E_1$-algebras by Dunn additivity. The functor
$$
    E_1-alg 
    \to
    Cat
$$
$$
    A 
    \mapsto
    A-mod
$$
is symmetric monoidal, so it will send a "banana" algebra in $E_1$-alg to a "banana" algebra in categories. In particular, the category of left $E_1$-modules over $A$ is an $E_2$-category; i.e., a braided monoidal (but not symmetric monoidal) category.

If you want the target to be 2-cats, rather than Cat, you can enhance by considering an $E_4$-algebra $A$, forget it to an $E_2$ algebra $A'$ and looking at the Morita 2-category of algebras over $A'$, or at the category of $E_2$-algebras over $A'$.

Comment: How does this pertain to classical invariants of knots? For example could we use something like Markarian's construction of a Weyl 3-algebra to recover the Jones polynomial from the braided category of representations of a quantum group? Is there a nice factorization homology viewpoint

Answer (score 4):

One simple way of producing symmetric monoidal $(\infty,n)$-categories with all duals is to form $n$-fold spans/correspondences, hence an [(∞,n)-category of spans](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity,n%29-category%20of%20spans) $Span_n(\mathbf{H})$ in some ambient $\infty$-topos $\mathbf{H}$.

This is discussed around section 3.2 in Jacob Lurie's "On the classification of TFTs".

In fact in $Span_n(\mathbf{H})$ every object is fully self-dual even. For low $n$ this is spelled out a bit at the beginning of these notes here

- Domenico Fiorenza, Urs Schreiber, et al,  *[Higher Chern-Simons local prequantum field theory](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Higher%20Chern-Simons%20local%20prequantum%20field%20theory)* .

For $X \in \mathbf{H} \hookrightarrow Span_n(\mathbf{H})$ any object, the corresponding invariant assigned to a closed framed $n$-manifold $\Sigma$ is $X^{\Pi(\Sigma)}$, where $\Pi(\Sigma) \in \infty Grpd \simeq L_{whe} sSet$ is the homotopy type of $\Sigma$ and the exponential notation denotes the powering of $\mathbf{H}$ over $\infty Grpd$.

While these are not the *quantum* invariants that you are looking for, this are in some precise sense the PREquantum invariants of a local field with moduli sstack $X$, before quantization. An exposition of this is in the lecture notes *[geometry of physics](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometry%20of%20physics)* in the section on *[prequantum field theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/prequantum%20field%20theory)*

A slight variant of this (also discussed there in more detail) works as follows: for $G \in Grp(\mathbf{H})$ an abelian $\infty$-group object, also the $(\infty,n)$-category $Span_n(\mathbf{H}_{/G})$ of $n$-fold spans in the slice $\infty$-topos over $G$ is symmetric monoidal with all duals. Objects are now maps $\exp(i S) : X \to G$ and their duals are now

$$
 \exp(-i S) : X \to G
$$

(using the inversion operation in $G$). As the notation suggests, the manifold invariant induced by that now are prequantum fields equipped with a local action functional.

These are *still* not the interesting quantum invariant that you are looking for, but this is now that data which upon "quantization" should give rise to them.

For discrete higher gauge theories (Dijkgraaf-Witten-type theories) this is indicated in sections 3 and 8 of [Freed-Hopkins-Lurie-Teleman](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Topological+Quantum+Field+Theories+from+Compact+Lie+Groups).

Answer (score 1):

Just a fun think to check out if you don't know, Crane and Yetter used a braided monoidal 2 category with duals to build their state-sum model for quantum gravity. I am not at a place now to explain how or why this is relevant, but I just wanted to make you aware. Consult their papers on Arxiv for the details.

Comment: Is that a very old paper? Does it have duals?

Comment: In some sense yes the papers are fairly old. The do have duals, and they construct the categories in question.

http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/hep-th/pdf/9409/9409167v1.pdf

and 

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9301062

are the ones I was speaking about specifically. Louis likes to say that the braided two category allows us to build the state-sum model "on the cheap". :) 

Hope this helps.

Comment: @B.Bischop, could you point to the page that you are thinking of? Thanks.

Comment: That's a braided monoidal category, and not a 2-category. Also, it can be shown that the Crane-Yetter invariant is a combination of Euler characteristic and signature, so it's uninteresting for either physics or mathematics.

Comment: There is this idea of "Hopf categories" which are supposed to be categorified Hopf algebras. Maybe these have braided monoidal 2-categories as representation categories?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at $(\infty,2)$ rather than $2$-categories, Luries paper on the cobordism hypothesis [link text](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0465) provides hints on how to find examples of categories with duals. Lurie sketches in Section 4.1 how to obtain examples for TQFTs using $E_n$-algebra objects in *good* symmetric monoidal $(\infty,1)$ categories $\mathcal{S}$. Given such a category $\mathcal{S}$, the $(\infty,n)$-category $Alg^o_{(n)}(\mathcal{S})$ of $E_n$-algebra objects has duals (4.1.14) and thus every object of it determines an $n$-dimensional TQFT by the cobordism hypothesis.

Particular examples can be obtained using topological chiral homology (4.1.18). This generalizes usual Hochschild cohomology of associative algebras.

Passing to $E_2$-algebras this should provide examples. It is also worth looking at 4.2 where the cobordism hypothesis is explored for smaller dimensions.

Comment: I think you mean it generalizes Hochschild homology, not cohomology. Also, the statement about $E_n$-algebras is true if you want to construct a TFT in the sense *not* of the tangle hypothesis. That is, $E_n$ algebras give n-categories with duals, but not braided monoidal n-categories with duals. To get the structure the OP wants, you'd rather consider a pair $(A,M)$ where $A$ is an $E_4$-algebra and $M$ is an $E_2$-algebra with an action of $A$. The associated TFT constructed from top. chi. homology (aka factorization homology) will then evaluate on 2,3,4-mflds with codim 2 embedded objects.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, you are right, I meant homology. And yes, the statement in this form gives symmetric monoidal $(\infty, 2)$-categories which wasn't asked for. But given a $E_n$-category $\mathcal{S}$ to start with, the $E_k$-algebra objects have the structure of an $E_{n-k}$-category. Starting with a $E_4$-category and looking at $E_2$-algebras in it, we should be able to obtain a $E_2$-object in  the $(\infty,1)$-category of $(\infty,2)$-categories, i.e a braided monoidal $(\infty, 2)$-category. If $\mathcal{S}=A$-Mod ($A$ an $E_4$-algebra), this should give your pair $(A,M)$.

Comment: At this point, all these examples are too sophisticated for me in that I don't have the background knowledge to decipher the notation. Supposing that the examples work, then is there a scheme to color $2$-tangle diagrams and get non-trivial invariants of oriented knotted surfaces?

Comment: @ScottCarter, I'm not sure if you mean something more elaborate by "color", but if you just mean labeling surfaces by elements of some set, yes, you can. For every color of a 2-tangle, you can for instance assign a different E_2 algebra. If you just take usual E_2 and E_4 algebras with the simplest actions on each other, you'd get invariants of knotted surfaces that are framed; i.e., with a trivialization of their normal bundle.